# How do I set auto.create.topics.enable=true in docker image johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper so that new topics are created automatically?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

In docker image [johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper](https://github.com/hey-johnnypark/docker-kafka-zookeeper) new topics are not created automatically. How do I set auto.create.topics.enable=true in this docker image [johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper](https://github.com/hey-johnnypark/docker-kafka-zookeeper) so that new topics are created automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Add the necessary environment variable to the image, `AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS=true`

https://github.com/hey-johnnypark/docker-kafka-zookeeper/blob/master/assets/scripts/start-kafka.sh#L74

Comment: Note - it's bad practice to run two services in the same container. Bitnami or Confluent images are regularly updated and production supported

Comment: This environment variable does NOT give the desired result, since it does not add "auto.create.topics.enable=true" to the config, but "\nauto.create.topics.enable=true"!

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation to use two containers in my unit test instead of one. However, in the unit test, it is more convenient for me to use a single container. My question is exactly this. In production, I don't need any containers for kafka, as well as auto-creation of topics.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. I can't control bugs in other people's code. If that doesn't work, use a different container. fast-data-dev is one example. You should be able to use compose files in tests as well

Comment: Note: you should be able to mount your own server properties file in the container to set whatever properties you need

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [wurstmeister image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka) for Kafka, you can add KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS environment variable to auto create a topic when runing the container.

Your docker-compose file might look as follows:

```
version: "2"


Services:

kafka-1:
image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest

ports:
  - "19092:19092"
depends_on:
  - zookeeper-1
  - zookeeper-2
  - zookeeper-3
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:12181,zookeeper-2:22181,zookeeper-3:32181
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:19092
  KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic1:1:1,topic2:1:1"
```

The first parameter is for the number of partionions, the second is for replication factor. For the above kafka configuration, the topic will have 1 partition and 1 replication-factor.